# Access to the specified resource has been forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use spring Security. I'm trying to redirect from profile.jsp. And have

Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

So, as i understand it's because of access failure somewhere. Page i want redirect to is also profile.jsp. So, i change options and i want to reload page. But have an exception

I've watched many similar on other topics, but still cant resolve

spring configuration

```
 <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/chat" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/profile" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/chat" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>

    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
            class="com.chat.my.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
            class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: please help anyone=))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
```

Could be that your login page also expect to be authenticated because of your

```
<intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try. But why i change /login, if error appear when i'm on profile.jsp(not login) and trying go by /add_photo(@Request par) to /profile